# Comparar dos arrays si son iguales "Ganaste"

Tags: javascript, array

Buen día, me encuentro en un dilema al poner console.log me muestra ya sea "Ganaste" "Segí participando" pero me marca error al momento de correrlo, como si algo estuviera mal, el lenguaje es javascript, la instrucción es la siguiente:

*Escribí la función **esPremioMayor** la cual recibiendo dos arrays, el primero con los números sorteados y el segundo con los números que jugaste. La función debe devolver el texto "Ganaste" si y solo si los 6 números jugados son iguales a los números sorteados, no importa el orden en el que hayan salido, de lo contrario devolverá la frase "Seguí participando".*

He intentado con dos posibles soluciones:

```js
let numerosSorteados = [ 12 , 4 , 40 , 33 , 13 , 17 ];
let numerosJugados = [ 4 , 12 ,13 , 17 , 33 , 40 ];
function esPremioMayor(numerosSorteados, numerosJugados){
    if( numerosSorteados = numerosJugados){ 
    return "Ganaste" 
    } else { 
        return "Seguí participando" 
    } 
 }
console.log(esPremioMayor( [ 12 , 4 , 40 , 33 , 13 , 17 ] , [ 4 , 12 , 13 , 17 , 33 , 40 ] ));
console.log(esPremioMayor( [ 12 , 4 , 40 , 33 , 13 , 17 ] ,[ 7, 19 , 22 , 36 , 41 , 42 ] ));
```

---

```js
let numerosSorteados = [ 12 , 4 , 40 , 33 , 13 , 17 ];
let numerosJugados = [ 4 , 12 ,13 , 17 , 33 , 40 ];
function esPremioMayor(numerosSorteados, numerosJugados)
{
   var cont = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i<=5;i++)
   {
      if(numerosJugados[i] == numerosSorteados[i])
      {
          cont++;
      }
   }

   if(cont == 6)
   {
      return "Ganaste";
   }
   else
   {
      return "Sigue jugando";
   }
}

console.log(esPremioMayor([ 12 , 4 , 40 , 33 , 13 , 17 ],[ 12 , 4 , 40 , 33 , 13 , 17 ]));
```

Agradecería si me pudieran orientar comentándome mis errores u observaciones, muchas gracias por leer. Saludos!!

Answer (score 2):

En tu primer intento estás usando una asignación en vez de una comparación.

```
if( numerosSorteados = numerosJugados){
```

debiera ser

```
if( numerosSorteados == numerosJugados){
```

Con respecto a la solución que estás intentando, y que te sugirieron en otra respuesta, le está dando importancia al orden de los arreglos. En el enunciado de tu ejercicio te dicen que no debe considerar el orden para evaluar la respuesta.

> La función debe devolver el texto "Ganaste" si y solo si los 6 números jugados son iguales a los números sorteados, **no importa el orden** en el que hayan salido,

Te dejo una solución que cumple con ese enunciado, pues ordena los arreglos antes de compararlos.

```js
function esPremioMayor(numerosSorteados, numerosJugados) {
  let sorteadosString = numerosSorteados
    .sort((a, b) => a - b).toString(),
    jugadosString = numerosJugados
    .sort((a, b) => a - b).toString();

  return (sorteadosString === jugadosString) ?
    'Ganaste' :
    'Sigue Participando';
}

console.log(esPremioMayor([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1]));

console.log(esPremioMayor([1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 1]));
```

El método `sort` de un arreglo siempre ordenará los elementos como texto si no le pasas un criterio de ordenamiento, por lo que un array de números pondrá antes un 10 que un 2 (el 1 es alfabéticamente menor). Por eso ordené los arreglos como

```
 arreglo.sort((a,b)=> a-b)
```

El criterio de ordenamiento [compareFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description) que opcionalmente le puedes pasar a `sort` debe devolver un número negativo si a<b, cero si son iguales y positivo si a>b.

[Puedes ver más información sobre el ordenamiento en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 0):

aquí tengo una ayuda lo que se hace es recorre dos for y me verifica si el numero esta en la lista, si esta me aumenta la variable conteo, despues me verifica si es igual a 6 y me devuelve true

```js
//el codigo funciona siempre y cuando los números no se repita
let firstArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let secondArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

rt= esPremioMayor(firstArray,secondArray);
console.info(rt);
if(rt){
  console.info('ganaste');
}else{
  console.error('no ganaste');
}


function esPremioMayor(numerosSorteados, numerosJugados){
  var conteo=0;
  for(i=0; i<firstArray.length; i++){
     for(f=0; f<secondArray.length; f++){
         if( firstArray[i] == secondArray[f]){
           conteo++;
         }
     }
  }
  if(conteo==6){
   // console.log('ganaste');
    return true;
  }else{
    //console.log('no ganaste');
    return false;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta marcos! Ya he encontrado la solución :D

Comment: bueno , si mi respuesta le ayuda a resolver el problema no se le olvide realizar la votación

Comment: @norawalker escribe tu solución en una respuesta. Alguien podría llegar acá buscando resolver tu misma duda.